# Origin of the interpretive tradition that Puranas describe multiple cycles?

Tags: scripture, puranas, interpretation, contradiction

I have often heard it said here that whenever there are two or more contradictory versions of a narrative found in the Puranas, that these versions should be seen as describing events in different universe cycles.

Where and when was this idea first explicitly mentioned? For all I know, this idea could have emerged on this very site.

Comment: Most of Hindu interpretation of scripture is based on the Mimamsa school's theory of scriptural exegesis. Mimamsa (and most other schools of Hinduism) believes that the Vedas are eternal and infallible. So, if there are any contradictory historical stories in the Vedas, then this means that these stories are referring to different time periods. And this theory would then extend to Puranas, which are also held to be infallible by the Vedanta sect.

Comment: Note that this interpretation only works if the text in consideration is infallible and un-altered.

Comment: @Ikshvaku But where and when was the origin of the idea that contradictory historical stories are referring to different time periods? Who first explicitly says this idea?

Comment: @Ikshvaku Do you have any quotes from Vedanta scholars saying that Puranas are without error?

Comment: @Ikshvaku Where did you learn the idea that the Puranas describe events in multiple cycles, even when not explicitly stated?

Comment: It is explicitly stated in the Brahma Sutras, and it is explicitly stated by scholars in lectures.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Which verses of BS mention this?

Comment: This one: https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48127.htm

Comment: @Ikshvaku "*A further objection is raised. Let it be admitted that after each pralaya of the kind called 'contingent' (naimittika), Pragâpati may proceed to create new Indras, and so on, in the way of remembering on the basis of the Veda the Indras, and so on, of preceding periods.*" Is this the sentence you are referring to?

Comment: @Ikshvaku Can you explain how it explicitly says that?

Comment: Because the opponent's argument is against the eternality of the Vedas. The Vedas contain historical stories, and talks about births of gods, etc. So how can the Vedas be eternal if it describes temporal events? The answer is that events in the Vedas repeat every age. The same logic extends to contradictory historical sections in the Vedas. If you want a more explicit statement, then I will have to find the specific granthas authored by the scholars. But otherwise, this is what the scholars teach in upanyasams.